# Where are the classes for vector,lists etc. are defined,in std namespace or in their respective header files?

Tags: c++, c++11

Currently,I am learning C++ and I observed that objects like vectors,lists can be used if we include their respective header file and std::object_name.Where these classes are actually defined,in their respective header files or in std namespace?

Comment: *" header files or in std namespace"* It is not exclusive. you can have namespace split across several files.

Comment: "namespace" and "include file" are orthogonal. Each include file can have any namespace inside, or no namespace, or multiple namespaces.

Comment: where is std namespace defined?

Comment: Please check this page http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `namespace std` is slit over many files, and not all defined in one place. Unlike a class, a namespace can be reopened and have new declarations added.

For example, the templates like `std::vector` are both declared and defined in their respective headers, because [Why can templates only be defined in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file).

Other members of `namespace std` can be declared in a header, and defined in a cpp file. That cpp file is probably already compiled into a runtime library that your program links to.